# Remove Chapter number from list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, function

The program im writing is taking a list of strings as the input and is trying to remove the Chapter numbers. I have the function written but it currenly does not work. I have provided my function and a sample of the output! Thank you!

```
def remove_chapter(chapter_header):
    for i in range(101):
        chapters="Chapter " + str(i)
        chapter_text=[my_string.replace(chapters,"") for my_string in chapter_header]
    return chapter_text
```

Here is the current output with the not working function:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avT2C.png)

Comment: You have an unconditional `return` statement inside a `for` loop. That's generally a bad sign, since it will exit the loop after the 1st iteration, i.e., after it has done the replacement for `"Chapter 0"`.

Comment: I have made the edits but it still does not read through correctly.

Comment: Before the for-loop `chapter_text = chapter_header[:]`.  Then inside your list comprehension iterate over `chapter_text`, not `chapter_header`.  And move `return` out of loop.

Comment: Or just replace the entire function with `[re.sub(r'Chapter \d+\s*', '', s) for s in chapter_header]`. Don't forget to `import re`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `strings` have a similar patter that you need to remove, with a few variations (`chapter number`), its better to use [`python.re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). With it, you have lot of flexibility in your `pattern matching`.

So, all you need to do :

```
>>> import re
>>> [ re.sub('Chapter \d+ ', '', string) for string in chapter_header ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : chapter_header = ['Chapter 1 It is ...','However little ...','Chapter 12 Lorem Ipsum']

OUT : ['It is ...', 'However little ...', 'Lorem Ipsum']
```

*Breaking it down, you pattern looks like :*

```
'Chapter'<whitespace>[number/s]<whitespace>
```

So, whenever this pattern is found, the string is substituted, or if not found, just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of chapters, we can drop the chapter and numbers up to the first word in each chapter.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


chapters = [
    "Chapter 1  It is a truth universally acknowledged ...",
    "Chapter 2  Mr. Bennet was among the earliest ...",
    "Chapter 3  Not all that Mrs. Bennet, however, with ...",
]
```

**Code**

```
pred = lambda x: (x == "Chapter") or x.isdigit() 
results = [list(it.dropwhile(pred, [word for word in chapter.split()])) for chapter in chapters]
results
```

Output

```
[['It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged', '...'],
 ['Mr.', 'Bennet', 'was', 'among', 'the', 'earliest', '...'],
 ['Not', 'all', 'that', 'Mrs.', 'Bennet,', 'however,', 'with', '...']]
```

---

**Details**

The list comprehension splits the chapters into lists and the words within the lists.  Equivalently:

```
for chapter in chapters:
    print([word for word in chapter.split()])

# ['Chapter', '1', 'It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged', '...']
# ['Chapter', '2', 'Mr.', 'Bennet', 'was', 'among', 'the', 'earliest', '...']
# ['Chapter', '3', 'Not', 'all', 'that', 'Mrs.', 'Bennet,', 'however,', 'with', '...']
```

Finally, [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) iterates each list and removes items until the predicate is not longer true.  In other words, keep dropping items up to the first that is neither `"Chapter"` nor a digit.

The resulting chapters can be rejoined as strings if desired.

```
[" ".join(chapter) for chapter in results]
# ['It is a truth universally acknowledged ...',
#  'Mr. Bennet was among the earliest ...',
#  'Not all that Mrs. Bennet, however, with ...']
```